# remove genymotion by saving the virtual devices

Tags: linux, ubuntu, genymotion, virtual-device-manager

I want to remove genymotion from my linux completely and it's important for me that save virtual devices that I have on it on my system. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

See https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002815177-How-to-uninstall-Genymotion-Desktop-completely-purge-

Your virtual device images should be in `$HOME/.Genymobile/Genymotion` - just backup this folder if you wish to keep them and Genymotion settings.

Comment: You mean I should take all of my genymotion folder from the path you said?! It's really large files. Isn't there the easier way?
By the way thanks a lot for answering:)

Comment: No problem. Well, you need at least `$HOME/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed` if you want to keep your virtual devices. However, I don't know whether Genymotion will "like" not to have the other folders and file. I personally backup everything in `$HOME/.Genymobile/Genymotion/` to be sure not to loose anything.

Comment: Another option is to export the virtual devices to OCI files from VirtualBox - see https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014413578-How-to-transfer-a-Genymotion-Desktop-virtual-device-to-another-Computer-